# Change default NTFS drivers ntfs-3g to paragon NTFS drivers(set as default)

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, ntfs, nautilus

I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS-32 BIT, kernel 3.2.0.52

Default NTFS-3G drivers are slow in R/W mode and i installed Paragon NTFS drivers for Linux. They worked like charm and i got read write speed = windows NTFS.

But the problem is that, i need to mount them as root or in /etc/fstab. If a partition is not mentioned in /etc/fstab entry, then in nautilus file browser, if click on left pane device list, it mounts with ntfs-3g drivers.

I also uninstalled ntfs-3g  drivers so that paragon ntfs drivers will take over but then native linux read only NTFS drivers came in place.

I am a noob and don't know what to do, i didn't find any tutorial and please tell me how to shift from default drivers to these commercial one.

I also want same file permission just like ntfs-3g (mount Read write and unmount by any user)

Thanks for help.